# How to upgrade MBP early 2015 SSD

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I am trying to look for a way to upgrade my **13 inch Macbook Pro Retina** SSD because it's too small right now (only 128GB).

I found out that currently only **OWC Aura** offers the upgrade SSD for this model of MBP, but is OWC trustable? How are their products?

Or is there any other brands that you know offers upgrade for **2015 early MBP**?

Note: I'm trying to install Windows with bootcamp, so external drives aren't really options for me :(

Many thanks!